# Effects of removing glacier_transition_time from deployed S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-glacier

I have a deployed s3 bucket with the following associated tf module

```
module "example_s3_bucket_v1" {
  source                  = "../modules/s3/s3_bucket"

  app_name                = "${var.tag_application_name}"
  aws_profile             = "${var.aws_profile}"
  aws_region              = "${var.aws_region}"
  bucket_name             = "example_bucket.v1"

  kms_key_arn             = "${data.aws_kms_alias.example_kms.target_key_arn}"
  glacier_transition_time = "1000"
  retention_time          = "2500"

  tag_app_id              = "${var.tag_application_id}"
  tag_application_name    = "${var.tag_application_name}"
  tag_component           = "${var.tag_component}"

  tags = {
    Name = "Example"
  }
}
```

The s3 bucket already has files stored within it, some of which have been migrated to glacier storage after their age exceeded the  `glacier_transition_time` variable. However, I do not want any files moved to glacier after this time period. Would restoring all files that are currently stored in glacier and then removing the `glacier_transition_time` variable and redeploying the bucket's config via terraform achieve this? Are there any side effects of removing this variable if the bucket is already deployed? Thank you.